# Yammer /autocomplete/ranked returning 401

Tags: yammer

If i make a `GET` request to other api calls like "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json", I get results back (this proves the office 365 bearer token i am using works).

If i make a request to Yammer `/autocomplete/ranked` using the following url:

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked?prefix=&models=group:10

or

https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/autocomplete/ranked?prefix=&models=group:10

This returns a `401`:

> Credentials are required to access this resource

Any ideas what might be wrong?

---

**API**: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/autocompleteranked

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm terribly sorry, but at present, this particular endpoint does not support using an O365 bearer token.

We are adding support for O365 credentials to more and more of our endpoints, but in the meantime you can access all of our endpoints using a Yammer-only token, documentation for which can be found here: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/app-registration

Source: I'm an engineer at Yammer and I've worked on these features.

Comment: Hi Nick, did we get this connected to O365 bearer token. Also, is there a list which say's which APIs are connected and which aren't.

Comment: Hi Nick, where can I find the documentation for autocomplete resources??